# How to 'Bridge'/'Stream'/'Forward' an Incoming HTTP Connection (Advanced Proxy)

Tags: php, proxy

Not sure if this is possible..basically a server forwards/bridges an incoming connection
Client -> Server -> Destination

Now, rather than a normal proxy script on the server(or a simple redirect),

1. the Destination sees the incoming connection as from the CLIENT (not from the SERVER).. aka masking the server
2. the Server in the middle streams the data back to the client(without
   downloading it first, then passing it)

Anyone know how to do this or something like it in PHP?

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a "Reverse Proxy".  You could try using one that is already implemented such as Squid, or mod_proxy for Apache.

Answer (score 0):

This is **possible**, but **not recommended** to be done **in PHP**.  Look at the [`Sockets`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) section of the PHP manual.  You would have to run this script as a CGI process instead of a webapp to use it to the full potential.